# Как узнать установлен ли Skype

Tags: java, android

Запускаю skype вот таким кодом.

```
  Intent skype_intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
            skype_intent.setClassName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main");
            skype_intent.setData(Uri.parse("skype: skype_name"));
            startActivity(skype_intent);
```

Все нормально. Но если на телефон нету skype, то приложение крашится.
Как мне по другому вызвать скайп, чтоб он не крашил приложение или сделать проверку на наличие skype на телефоне. Если есть запустить код, если нет вывести "У вас нету skype"?

Comment: а что мешает обработать исключение (try catch) и выводить "у вас нет скайпа" при краше. Как именно происходит краш?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11392276/6266408

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                     android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.skype.raider/com.skype.raider.Main}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Думаю в пояснении данный код не нуждается:

```
private boolean isAppInstalled(String packageName) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean installed = false;
    try {
       pm.getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
       installed = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
       installed = false;
    }
    return installed; 
}
```